# phonegap app only secure origins are allowed

Tags: geolocation, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am developing phonegap android app
I want to get user current location so I used to
that plugin

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"    source="npm" spec="1.0.1" />
```

When I tried to get user current location it give that error in that line

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

It call onError location and give that error

```
Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://goo.gl /Y0ZkNV).
```

How can I make phonegap security?

Answer (score 1):

Service workers only via **https**. The easiest way around it is to go to `http://localhost:3000` instead of the IP address of the computer.

**Full code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log(device.cordova);
          var onSuccess = function(position) {

          console.log('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
          'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
          'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
          'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
          'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
          'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
          'Timestamp: '         + new Date(position.timestamp)      + '\n');
          };
          function onError(error) {
             console.log('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
          }

          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        }


    </script>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: what do you mean when say http://localhost:3000.... I don't make any call or service call...I used same code but it give https error..what is your webconfig can you share it please?

Comment: are you testing in mobile or browser ?

Comment: in mobile as app not browser